# hive - show table's column details only

Tags: hive

I have created a HIVE partition table and when I run `describe table` I see other table properties as well as the table column details. If I want to see only the table column details, then what command can I use?

```
create table t1 (x int, y int, s string) partitioned by (z date) stored as sequencefile;
describe t1;

+--------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--+
|         col_name         |       data_type       |        comment        |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--+
| x                        | int                   |                       |
| y                        | int                   |                       |
| s                        | string                |                       |
| z                        | date                  |                       |
|                          | NULL                  | NULL                  |
| # Partition Information  | NULL                  | NULL                  |
| # col_name               | data_type             | comment               |
|                          | NULL                  | NULL                  |
| z                        | date                  |                       |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--+
```

Can the last 5 rows be avoided?

```
                         | NULL                  | NULL                  |
| # Partition Information  | NULL                  | NULL                  |
| # col_name               | data_type             | comment               |
|                          | NULL                  | NULL                  |
| z                        | date                  |                       |
```

Also what does this NULL | NULL row means?

Comment: Which other properties do you see that you don't want? can you give an example of the desired output?

Comment: The last 5 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is this configuration parameter:

[`set hive.display.partition.cols.separately=false`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-hive.display.partition.cols.separately)

From [hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-DescribeTable/View/Column):

> In Hive 0.10.0 and earlier, no distinction is made between partition columns and non-partition columns while displaying columns for DESCRIBE TABLE. From Hive 0.12.0 onwards, they are displayed separately.
>   In Hive 0.13.0 and later, the configuration parameter [hive.display.partition.cols.separately](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-hive.display.partition.cols.separately) lets you use the old behavior, if desired ([HIVE-6689](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6689)). For an example, see the test case in the [patch for HIVE-6689](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12635956/HIVE-6689.2.patch).